# How to develop awesome WM rc.lua using IDE

Tags: linux, awesome-wm, lua

I'm aware that awesome includes its own Lua interpreter but developing a large rc.lua file with a "simple" text editor is too troublesome.

Is there a way to develop the rc.lua in an IDE like ZeroBrane?

I couldn't find a way to include awesome's libraries in my ZeroBrane project.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run the script from the command line (such that it finds `gears`, `awful` and other awesome libraries), you should be able to load mobdebug (this is the debugger used in the IDE) and start debugging as explained in the [remote debugging section](https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-remote-debugging) of the ZeroBrane Studio documentation. I'm not sure which Lua version the awesome libraries are using, so make sure you reference the correct version of the dynamic libraries (as mentioned in the instructions).